# how to prevent sshd related messages from being written to systemd journal log

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, sd-card, systemd-journald

I'm running a raspberry pi on an SD card and the logs are constantly hammered with failed login attempts from botnets. Beyond filling the logs with useless information, this is putting wear and tear on my SD card. How can I prevent failed logins from being written to the various logs in /var/log/*?

I know about the steps listed on https://alantechreview.blogspot.com/2022/03/improving-raspberry-pi-sd-card-lifetime.html for stopping failed ssh logins from hitting /var/log/auth.log and /var/log/btmp but there doesn't seem to be a way to stop those same messages from hitting the systemd journal (/var/log/journal/*/system.journal)

To be clear, I still want logs that are saved to disk, just not logs polluted with absolutely useless information (to me).

Note/update: the SD wear and tear caused by saving the systemd journal is somewhat limited by the fact that it's not synced to disk after every write. BUT: 90% of the bytes in the journal are failed login attempts. Even though writes are batched that's still a lot of data 24/7, and also reduces space for actually useful logs (the default journal size on the pi is 16mb, so only 1.6mb are going to be left over for useful data; I could increase the log file size but it already takes a long time to scan the whole database).

Comment: Are you really absolutely with no doubt sure you want to miss out on security critical events on a machine which is open to the internet and under constant attack of botnets while possibly also connected to your home network where all your other devices with possibly valuable or irreplaceable data reside? You should be aware that if you do disable the one most important feature of logging, which are the access logs, that then there is absolutely no easy chance to detect a security breach and therefore appropriately respond to a security breach.

Comment: I'd honestly start simply by disabling password auth. That should take care of most login attempts before there's even something to log. And, if your RPi is exposed to the internet, that is anyways a very reasonable security measure you'd want to take.

Comment: by the way, by default, journald syncs to disk every 5 minutes. That should put absolutely negligible wear and tear on your SD card. Not sure you're actually solving a problem that exists!

Comment: @mashuptwice I defy you to find anything useful in the mountain of failed login attempts. Have you ever inspected them yourself? We are talking 1 or more lines added to the log every second.

Comment: @Marcus Müller I agree that's the intended behavior but my reading of the journal man page suggests that sshd is making it sync every second or so because of the sshd message priority:  "The timeout before synchronizing journal files to disk. After syncing, journal files are placed in the OFFLINE state. Note that syncing is unconditionally done immediately after a log message of priority CRIT, ALERT or EMERG has been logged."
I could be wrong here - is there a way to monitor if the disk has actually been touched? A simple ls-l shows the modtime updating about once a second.

Comment: Using journalctl -p I was able to determine that the SSHD logs are not high enough priority to trigger a sync (they are priority=INFO). I'm going to update the question to reflect that. I still think it's bad to have all the sshd failed logins there, however, as the log is so full of those SSHD notifications that there's a lot less space left over for actually useful messages (90% of messages are failed logins, so the actual effective journal size becomes 1.6mb).

Comment: @AlRo here's something useful to do with all those failed login messages: run fail2ban, and have it automatically add/remove firewall rules to block future connection attempts from the same IP address for a while.   It's even possible to create fail2ban rules that increase the ban time for repeat attempts from the same address.

Comment: @cas that's a reasonable suggestion. I'm sure it varies a lot, but a few spot checks suggest that each IP address knocking on my door only make repeated attempts to connect over a few minutes. By an hour later there's zero overlap. So in the end fail2ban would help, but maybe not that much unless the ban rule were quite strict, risking of course false positives, and the iptables database would get huge.

Comment: @AlRo yes, I do check the logs on my personal servers for successful authentications occasionally with `grep` and also feed them to fail2ban. Note that by setting the bantime to a relatively short amount you can prevent your firewall rules from growing.

Comment: @AlRo Re: challenge to find something in a heap of unsuccessful login attempt logs: It's not hard to filter `journalctl`; for example `journalctl -o json | jq -C 'select (.SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=="sshd") | select( .MESSAGE| strings | test ("(authentication failure|connection closed|failed password|user unknown)";"i")|not)'` will give me a list of JSON dictionaries with only log messages from sshd (could ask for PAM or other modules) which are not auth failures. (you could do the same using journalctl "select unit" and some regexes, but this is to show you can do rather clever queries!)